# can I use manhattan distance function on hartigan wong kmeans clustering

Tags: r, clustering, k-means, distance-functions

I would like to perform Hartigan Wong clustering on high dimensional data. As I understand, Manhattan distance works better than the Euclidean distance in higher dimensions. 
I have been using the K-means clustering which uses the Euclidian distance function.

I have two question:

1. Can we use a different distance function, such as Manhattan distance, in k-means clustering?
2. If so, Does changing the distance function to Manhattan distance in Hartigan Wong algorithm reduce the curse of dimensionality?

Comment: This is what I meant, Does changing the distance to Manhattan distance in Hartigan Wong algorithm reduce the curse of dimensionality and improve the performance of the algorithm?

Comment: Are you talking about K-NN or K-means? These are different algorithms, used to perform different tasks.

Comment: I am talking about kmeans

Comment: KMeans doesn't work with Manhattan, because of the mean. And it doesn't solve the curse of dimensionality either.

Comment: Thanks @Anony-Mousse. That's the kind of response I was expecting. Do you know why it does not solve the curse dimensionality?

Comment: One does not simply solve the curse of dimensionality. That is why it's a curse and not the "switch of dimensionality" that you only need to turn off. When \sum (xi-yi)² become too similar, \sum |xi-yi| can't behave fundamentally different.

Comment: @Anony-Mousse, yes, means are used to calculate new centroids, but i think if somobody tries Manhattan, there might be interesting results.Most of the time these will be similar to Eucledian only .

Comment: Yes, of course they will be similar. But they won't even be *local* optimums. They are just results without any guaranteed quality. And if you would read the theory of Hartigan and Wong, you will see that it requires *squared* Euclidean distance.

Comment: The main feature of euclideam distance used in Hartigan-Wong 1979 paper is that the sum of squared distance from a set to a point can be explicitly minimized. The sum of L1 distances can also be easily minimized (at the median). The minimum may not be uniques since the L1 norm is not strictly convex.  In a 2022 pre-print paper, Godichon-Baggioni and Surendran study the choice of k when minimizing sums of euclidean distances (no squared distance), which would produce clusters that are less sensitive to "extreme" points than the clusters from k-means.

Comment: "Clustering" is an instance of unsupervised learning, so there are no wrong ways of clustering,. As long as the result is usefull, the method is good.